# Auth::user() is null after successful Passport authentication

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-passport

I am using password for user Authentication, and I after every authentication I assign a secure cookie that stores the passport token. A am being able to successfully authenticate using the `Auth::attempt()` method, but the `Auth::user()` is null. Even in the same controller, on the logout() method the user is undefined and I can't even `Auth::logout()`.

Login method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $credentials = \request(['email', 'password']);
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $token = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->accessToken;
        $cookie = $this->getSessionCookie($token);
        return response()
            ->json([
                'user' => $user,
                'token' => $token,
            ], 200)
            ->cookie(
                $cookie['name'],
                $cookie['value'],
                $cookie['minutes'],
                $cookie['path'],
                $cookie['domain'],
                $cookie['secure'],
                $cookie['httponly'],
                $cookie['samesite']
            );
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Invalid Credentials',
        ], 422);
    }
}
```

Logout method:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->token()->each(function ($token, $key) {
        $token->delete();
    });
    $cookie = \Cookie::forget('auth_token');
    Auth::logout();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Logged out successfully.'
    ], 200)->withCookie($cookie);
}
```

Here the `Auth::logout()` produces `Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist.` Otherwise the logout is successful.

My API routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {

    // Authentication
    Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'AuthController@sendPasswordResetLink');
    Route::post('/password/update', 'AuthController@callResetPassword');

    // Articles
    Route::get('/articles', 'ArticleController@index');

    Route::middleware(['auth.header', 'auth:api'])->group(function () {
        // Get Logged in User
        Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->user(); // returns the actual logged in user
        });

        // Articles
        Route::post('/articles', 'ArticleController@store');
        Route::get('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');
        Route::put('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@update');
        Route::delete('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@destroy');

        // Log Out
        Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
});
```

Example controller where `Auth::user()` is null:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = \auth()->user(); // null
        $user = Auth::user(); // null
        $user = $request->user(); // null
    }
}
```

In index method I know why the user is null since the route is not wrapped in `auth:api` middleware, but how would I get the auth user in this method even if it's not required.

I am sure I am missing something but I don't know what. I'll be happy to provide more code.

**EDIT:**
My `auth.api` middleware:

```
class AuthenticationHeader
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->bearerToken()) {
            if ($request->hasCookie('auth_token')) {
                $token = $request->cookie('auth_token');
                $request->headers->add(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is auth.header middleware for ?

Comment: @FouèdMoussi it appends the bearer token secure http cookie to the authorization header

Comment: Could you disable it for instance and try again ?

Comment: @FouèdMoussi I did, but the thing is, without the bearer token, the passport's `auth:api` rejects request, its a simple middleware really, I updated the code, you can look at it.

Comment: I am getting the same issue any solution you found?

Comment: @joy this was a long time ago, but as far as I can remember you need to consider the guard that you are using for authentication, if web start the session and store the user, if auth give back token which you will pass on each request.

Answer (score 0):

API Routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {

    // Authentication
    Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'AuthController@sendPasswordResetLink');
    Route::post('/password/update', 'AuthController@callResetPassword');

    // Articles
    Route::get('/articles', 'ArticleController@index');

    Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
        // Get Logged in User
        Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->user(); // returns the actual logged in user
        });

        // Articles
        Route::post('/articles', 'ArticleController@store');
        Route::get('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');
        Route::put('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@update');
        Route::delete('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@destroy');

        // Log Out
        Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
});
```

Auth Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Mail\ResetPassword;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\BaseController as BaseController;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
//use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;

class AuthController extends BaseController
{
    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Authenticate api
     * @param  Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
                $success['token'] = 'Bearer ' . $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

                $success['user'] = $user->only('id', 'name', 'email', 'avatar');

                return $this->sendResponse($success, 'User logged in successfully.');
            } else {
                return $this->sendError('Please verify your Email.', [], 400);
            }
        }

        return $this->sendError('Wrong Credentials.', [], 400);
    }

    /**
     * Register API
     * @param  Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
            //'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        $name = $request->input('name');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

        if ($user) {
            return $this->sendError('This email address is already taken. Please try another.', [], 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => bcrypt($password)
        ]);

        $user->sendApiEmailVerificationNotification();


        return $this->sendResponse([], 'Please confirm yourself by clicking on verify user button sent to you on your email.');
    }

    /**
     * Send reset password email API
     * @param  Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetLink(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        $email = $request->input('email');


        $response = Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $email], function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return $this->sendResponse([], 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!');
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return $this->sendError('We can\'t find a user with that e-mail address.', [], 400);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reset password action API
     * @param  Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function callResetPassword(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request),
            function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        if ($response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET) {
            return $this->sendResponse([], 'User password has been successfully reset.');
        } else {
            return $this->sendError($response, [], 400);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logout API
     * @param  Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            Auth::user()->oauthAcessTokens()->delete();
            return $this->sendResponse([], 'User logged out successfully.');
        }
    }
}
```

Base Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
    * success response method.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function sendResponse($result, $message = null)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $result
        ];

        if (!empty($message)) {
            $response['message'] = $message;
        }

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }


    /**
    * return error response.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function sendError($error, $errorMessages = [], $code = 422)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $error,
        ];

        if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
            $response['data'] = $errorMessages;
        }

        return response()->json($response, $code);
    }
}
```